# One more question about the "Double-Checked-Locking"

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, jvm, singleton

I have modified a "normal" DCL singleton case according to "effective java" #83, as below.

```
import java.util.Date;

public class MySystem {
    private Date date = new Date();

    private MySystem() {};

    private static volatile MySystem instance;

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public static MySystem getInstance() {
        MySystem my = instance;
        if (my == null) {
            synchronized (MySystem.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = my = new MySystem();
                }
            }
        }
        return my;
    }
}
```

But when I run it, NullpointerException will be throwed in a very high proportion. And when I modify it as below, everything is ok. Why?

```
import java.util.Date;

public class MySystem {
    private Date date = new Date();

    private MySystem() {};

    private static volatile MySystem instance;

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public static MySystem getInstance() {
        MySystem my = instance;
        if (my == null) {
            synchronized (MySystem.class) {
                my = instance;
                if (my == null) {
                    instance = my = new MySystem();
                }
            }
        }
        return my;
    }
}
```

The main is as below. It's hard to figure out the difference.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(MySystem.getInstance().getDate());
            }
        }.start();

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(MySystem.getInstance().getDate());
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: side note:direct  use `new Date()` ->`private Date date = new Date();`  instend of initialize in contractor.

Comment: because in your case you are taking class level lock.they will share same context. if you put synchronized  on method level then every thing work fine in both case.

Comment: Yes, the example in "Effective Java" uses method level sync. I can't catch you, would you like to give more details about the context? @ArunKumar

Comment: You do know that [double checked locking was long ago proven to be a broken pattern](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html), right? And that his whitepaper was signed by Josh Bloch and other java luminaries...

Comment: @Bohemian Yes, my java version is java8, so I think the volatile DCL version is ok now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get NPE when the following happens:

```
public static MySystem getInstance() {
    MySystem my = instance;
    if (my == null) {                            // (1) instance was null => my is null and synchronized block is entered.
        synchronized (MySystem.class) {
            if (instance == null) {              // (2) instance was updated from another thread and is not null anymore.
                instance = my = new MySystem();
            }
        }
    }
    return my;
}
```

You will notice that in this scenario, the the reference `instance` is not copied into `my`, which remains `null`. You can try the following to verify:

```
public static MySystem getInstance() {
    MySystem my = instance;
    if (my == null) {
        synchronized (MySystem.class) {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new MySystem();
            }
        }
        my = instance;
    }
    return my;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The differnece is this line:

```
my = instance;
```

You're making both object reference one place on JVM's heap. After that you're calling:

```
my = new MySystem();
```

which makes both `my` and `instance` not null (you cannot chain `=` operator, so only `my` is instantiated). Then after calling this:

```
MySystem.getInstance().getDate()
```

you're not invoking method on null.

When it's synchronized, then the second thread is waiting for instantiation of `my` (for this line `my = instance` to be invoked) and doesn't get NPE.

Comment: then what is the use of synchronized here?

Comment: Ok, maybe it wasn't clear enough, I've added it to my answer, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let me to explain it step by step.
Thread A: my == null.
Thread B: my == null, then get sync, then "instance = my = new MySystem()", and return my, which is not null.
Thread A: get sync, then "instance != null", and return my, which is null.

NPE, bang! So the "my = instance" before second check is necessary.

How to explain the example in "Effective Java"?

```
// Double-check idiom for lazy initialization of instance fields
private volatile FieldType field;
private FieldType getField() {
    FieldType result = field;
    if (result == null) { // First check (no locking)
        synchronized(this) {
        if (field == null) // Second check (with locking)
            field = result = computeFieldValue();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```